# Windows Server 2019: Google NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-server-2019

On one Windows Server 2019 I cannot connect to services from Google because I receive the **NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID** error.

I cannot even connect to the Google homepage (https://www.google.com).

It seems that the certification authority is not trusted on my server, but I cannot understand why as I am not having such error on other HTTPS websites, and I cannot immagine any particular event which caused this.

How I can debug?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this problem was present in both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, and maybe some other software.

I solved the problem fixing the list of Trusted Root Certificates in Windows with the following PowerShell script:

```
certutil.exe -generateSSTFromWU roots.sst
$sstStore = ( Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\me\Desktop\roots.sst )
$sstStore | Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

Now that websites are correctly trusted.